# Number of rows in which two or more specified values appear

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following table:

```
n1|n2|n3|n4|n5
 1| 5| 4| 7|26
26|80|75| 1|10
 5| 3| 2| 1|4
45|26| 1| 3|66
```

I'm trying to get the number of rows in which two or more specified values appear.
In the above table, for example, 26 and 1 appear in 3 rows.

Is there a fast way to do this in mySQL or should I build some function in PHP?

Thank you very much for your help

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM your_table
WHERE 1 IN (n1,n2,n3,n4,n5) AND 26 IN (n1,n2,n3,n4,n5)
```

Comment: @xdazz What about if I have 3 numbers (26, 1, and 10) and I want to get the number of rows in which two of them appear (e.g.: 26 and 1, 26 and 10, 1 and 10)?

Comment: @WeContest You could add OR condtion.

Comment: Yes, but this way it will find also rows containing only 1 number. I want rows containing at least 2 numbers (of the 3)